# Laravel Excel - Catch exception in queued export with chain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

**Context:** I have an export that I want to mail to its intended recipients once it is stored.

I do this inside a Job class.

```php
public function handle(): void
{
    (new ReportExport($this->report, $this->date))->queue($this->report->path)
        ->chain([
            new NotifyReportRecipients($this->report),
        ]);
}
```

Inside the export, I'm using the **FromGenerator** concern.

```php
public function generator(): Generator
{
    $query = DB::query()->select(...)->from(...)->where(...);

    return $query->cursor()->getIterator();
}
```

This already works.

---

Now, I want to send a **different** notification but only in the case the export is empty, so I'm trying to cause an exception so I can handle it in the Job class.

```php
use Path\To\MyException;

public function generator(): Generator
{
    $query = DB::query()->select(...)->from(...)->where(...);

    throw_if($query->count() === 0, MyException::class);

    return $query->cursor()->getIterator();
}
```

But it does not work since the Laravel-excel developers didn't implement a catch method for their `QueuedExport` class.

```php
public function handle(): void
{
    (new ReportExport($this->report, $this->date))->queue($this->report->path)
        ->chain([
            new NotifyReportRecipients($this->report),
        ])
        ->catch(function (MyException $e) {
            new NotifyReportRecipientsAboutEmptyReport($this->report),
        });
        //  Error  Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueExport::catch()
}
```

I've tried using a try...catch block

```php
public function handle(): void
{
    try {
        (new ReportExport($this->report, $this->date))->queue($this->report->path)
            ->chain([
                new NotifyReportRecipients($this->report),
            ]);
    } catch (MyException $e) {
        NotifyReportRecipientsAboutEmptyReport::dispatch($this->report);
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

I've tried following the documentation for Laravel excel and just add a `failed` method to my Export class but this doesn't work either.

```php
use Path\To\MyException;

public function failed(Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof MyException) {
        NotifyReportRecipientsAboutEmptyReport::dispatch($this->report);
    }
}

public function generator(): Generator
{
    $query = DB::query()->select(...)->from(...)->where(...);

    throw_if($query->count() === 0, MyException::class);

    return $query->cursor()->getIterator();
}
```

What's worse, is that the chain just dispatches the Notification regardless.

Does anyone know the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: failed method in the export class was added since version 3.1.25 of laravel excel. what version do you have installed?

Comment: According to the lock file and `composer show`, I have the 3.1.51 version installed.